# I can see my deleted answer, but not my deleted question?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted)

> Related: [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted)

Yesterday I asked a question [which was poorly stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426507/binding-a-second-vertex-buffer-seems-to-spoil-my-first-vertex-buffer-opengl-oes) (mostly because I didn't understand the problem).  Nobody could answer it, and at the moment I thought it was unsalvageable, so I deleted it.  Of course I saved the question locally, because I always do that, you know.

Now I want to re-ask that question better worded (which I can! thanks to local .txt files), *but* it begs the question, why can I see my deleted answers

[image: a best guess wrong answer I made]

(which was  a best-guess wrong answer I made),

but I can't see my deleted questions?

[image: deleted question]

You know I deleted it, why can't I access it?

Comment: I bet it was either an oversight that became a feature. Or it was an attempt to reduce the amount of whining when a question is deleted by the community.

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate, but I'm not going to look for it since it's probably [status-declined] and this is absurd behavior

Comment: You haven't re-asked it *yet*, right?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Nyet

Comment: I really can't think of any good reason you can't see your own deleted posts *with a link*. Sure, deleted posts shouldn't be listed because blah blah; but the *owner* viewing their own deleted post doesn't seem like a risk in any way.

Comment: @Mysticial if anything it increases the amount of whining; I've seen plenty of "why was my question deleted--also I can't even see it" on Meta.

Answer (score 8):

I really think this needs to be changed so that users have 10K views on content that they've deleted themselves. This would not only help avoid problems with people who are caught by the question ban, requiring moderator intervention, but it would also help in situations where a < 10K user decides to try to improve his/her deleted post and then undelete it.

If there is some sort of problem with this or way that a user could game the system, then we should figure that out and solve *that* problem.

As an aside, I visited your link and flagged your post for reopening. Stay tuned to see if a Stack Overflow moderator can undelete that for you.

Comment: Can you do that, if _I've_ deleted it?

Comment: @bobobobo: 10k users and moderators can see and flag a deleted question, whether it was deleted by the asker or not.